# linux passwords in configuration files

Tags: linux, security, passwords

Some programs on linux that use configuration files, want me to enter my password in plain text in one of their configuration files. For example newsbeauter, the rss reader wants me to enter my google account password in a ~/.newsbeauter/config if I want to read google reader feeds. Mutt also sort of wants a password in a text file, but gives an option of entering it on every login.

Is there any secure workaround to storing a password in a config file like that (eg for newsbeauter)? I was thinking of running the app as root, but that doesn't seem right. Or somehow creating and deleting the file everytime I use the app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Tweaking permissions will not protect against an adversary who has access to your disks (stolen laptop).

You cannot protect against an adversary that has root on your running system, but you can protect yourself against a stolen disk, or various not-too-smart malicious software, with these two techniques:

- Set up a small encrypted filesystem (use dm-crypt or truecrypt, for instance), then replace your config files with symbolic links that point to some place in the encrypted partition. This is simple to deploy, but puts you at risk when the encrypted fs is mounted

  ```
  mount encrypted fs under /mnt/crypt
  cp ~/.application/config /mnt/crypt/app-config
  ln -s /mnt/crypt/app-config ~/.application/config
  unmount encrypted fs to lock config
  ```
- Replace your config files with named pipes (mkfifo). That will only work well if the application reads the config in a single pass; upon startup, the app will block on reading the config file, until you write it in the named pipe. You can then store an encrypted version of the file somewhere else (use for instance gpg); when required, decrypt the contents with gpg and send it on the fly to the pipe. This is a bit safer as you must allow by hand each access to the file, but is maybe less convenient.

  ```
   # setup
   gpg -e -r my-address@domain.com <~/.application/config ~/.application/config.pgp
   mkfifo ~/.application/config
   # run application, application hangs waiting for config
   gpg -d <~/.application/config.pgp >~/.application/config
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Running non-critical software as root is almost never a good idea.

What you should do instead is change the permissions of these files so that only you (the user who is running these programs) can read them. To remove e.g. read, write and execution permission for anybody but you on a file `mine.conf`, you would under your accout

```
chmod og-rwx mine.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another trick is to put the config file inside a directory but take away the read permissions for this too so that you can't see inside
just do

> chmod a-r whatever/

So that you can only see inside it if you are root, or you can just remember what the file is called too, but you would still be able to do everything to the file inside, as long as you know the file name or if you are root, to do

> sudo ls whatever/